# Snowflake SQL rows with minimum and maximum values for each partition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rank

I need to find the maximum and minimum values for a summed column over table partitions.

The inner query is:

```
select 
ss_store_sk,
d.d_year,
d.d_moy,
sum(ss_quantity) as total_sales,
rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by sum(ss_quantity) desc) as "rank"
from store_sales
join date_dim as d on d.d_date_sk = ss_sold_date_sk
where d.d_year != 2003 and d.d_moy != 1
group by 
ss_store_sk,
d.d_year,
d.d_moy
```

and this will produce a table like below.

| SS_STORE_SK | D_YEAR | D_MOY | TOTAL_SALES | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 182 | 1999 | 12 | 60836090 | 1 |
| 182 | 1998 | 11 | 60792623 | 2 |
| 182 | 2001 | 10 | 60615582 | 3 |
| 182 | 2000 | 9 | 60459371 | 4 |
| 18 | 1998 | 12 | 232323 | 1 |
| 18 | 2001 | 11 | 123244 | 2 |
| 18 | 2000 | 10 | 3422 | 3 |

I can get the max value row for TOTAL_SALES by the following:

```
with minmax as (
inner query
)
select * from minmax where "rank" =1
```

But how do I get the minimum value row for TOTAL_SALES for each SS_STORE_SK? The result I need will look like below.  But it will be sufficient to just be able to get the min ranked rows by TOTAL_SALES separately.

| SS_STORE_SK | D_YEAR | D_MOY | TOTAL_SALES | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 182 | 1999 | 12 | 60836090 | 1 |
| 182 | 2000 | 9 | 60459371 | 4 |
| 18 | 1998 | 12 | 232323 | 1 |
| 18 | 2000 | 10 | 3422 | 3 |

I am using Snowflake SQL.

Comment: Your title and question say "minimum" but your description is the "maximum".

Comment: He wants to have both maximum and minimum sales for each SS_STORE_SK.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.  Yes i need both the min and max.  I can get the max but have been unable to get the min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to `rank()` window function: one to rank in descending order of `sum(ss_quantity)` and one to rank in ascending order. Then just select first row from both the rankings.

```
with minmax as
(
   select 
   ss_store_sk,
   d.d_year,
   d.d_moy,
   sum(ss_quantity) as total_sales,
   rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by sum(ss_quantity) desc) as "rank"
   rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by sum(ss_quantity) ) as "rank2"
   from store_sales
   join date_dim as d on d.d_date_sk = ss_sold_date_sk
   where d.d_year != 2003 and d.d_moy != 1
   group by 
   ss_store_sk,
   d.d_year,
   d.d_moy
)
select * from minmax where rank =1 or rank2=1
```

Answer (score 1):

A more consice way to filter rows based on windowed function:

```
select 
  ss_store_sk,
  d.d_year,
  d.d_moy,
  sum(ss_quantity) as total_sales
from store_sales
join date_dim as d on d.d_date_sk = ss_sold_date_sk
where d.d_year != 2003 and d.d_moy != 1
group by ss_store_sk, d.d_year, d.d_moy
qualify rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by total_sales desc) = 1
     or rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by total_sales) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max()` window function:

```
select ss_store_sk, d.d_year, d.d_moy,
       sum(ss_quantity) as total_sales,
       rank() over (partition by ss_store_sk order by sum(ss_quantity) desc) as "rank",
       max(sum(ss_quantity)) over (partition by ss_store_sk)
from store_sales join
     date_dim d
     on d.d_date_sk = ss_sold_date_sk
where d.d_year <> 2003 and d.d_moy <> 1
group by ss_store_sk, d.d_year, d.d_moy;
```

Of course, if you wanted the minimum, you would use `min()` instead.

Comment: @user2907249 . . . You prefer a subquery to simply using a window function?